# PyCharm: Ctrl+F not able of finding substrings (only full strings)

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm not sure why but I was sure that <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> can find all occurrences of a string in a file.

Say I want to find all occurrences of variables that ends with `_cfg` or all imports ending with `time` in a file and it turns out that <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> is not able to find it.

It can only find full strings such as `user_cfg` or `datetime` but not when you put a substring of the name into the search fields.

Is there any option that I can turn on full substring search in a file?

```
PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-233.14475.56, built on February 26, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+1-b1087.17 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
  ide.experimental.ui=true
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  com.chesterccw.excelreader (2024.2.1-233)
  Key Promoter X (2023.3.0)
  com.dsoftware.ghtoolbar (1.17.0)
  com.github.copilot (1.4.18.4775)
  net.ashald.envfile (3.4.2)
```

I tried testing with multiple substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by having `Words` activated. Try toggling it and see if that helps.

(On Windows it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or clicking the `W` next to the search string. Not sure what it looks like on Mac.)

[image]